# Using REGEXP_REPLACE for a pattern of string matching

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I have this string: `ABC1111|~@SERIAL_NUM_ONE@~|~@SERIAL_NUM_TWO@~|~@SERIAL_NUM_THREE@~`

Now I want to replace, `~@anything@~` with `~@` so that my string looks like: `ABC1111|~@|~@|~@`

How do I do this in Oracle? I think we should use REGEXP_REPLACE to get this done! But not able to figure it out. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp_replace('ABC1111|~@SERIAL_NUM_ONE@~|~@SERIAL_NUM_TWO@~|~@SERIAL_NUM_THREE@~',
               '~@.+?@~',
               '~@')
```

- `.+?` is non-greedy expression and returns, `ABC1111|~@|~@|~@`
- `.+` is greedy expression, tried to mach as much as possible and returns `ABC1111|~@`

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/16907).